# Should I do my update in the database or in Python?

Tags: python, django

My original questions on SO were about how to efficiently link lots of records. Some of you guys really helped out! Here's what I found. **Your situation might be different!**

"It's best to do the heavy lifting in the database."

I'd heard that and seen it written many times. **WOW** was that wrong! This tiny little writeup chronicles what was actually a major breakthrough in my product's development.

Your app tracks the ownership of cars, and correlates data to them. Here are some models:

```
# There are ~2M OwnershipRecord models
class OwnershipRecord(models.Model):
  vin = models.CharField(...)
  saledate = models.DateField(...)
  active = models.BooleanField(...)

# There are ~1M MaintenanceRecord models
class MaintenanceRecord(models.Model):
  vin = models.CharField(...)
  ownership_record = models.ForeignKey(OwnershipRecord, ...)
  mileage = models.DecimalField(...)
  date_in_shop = models.DateField(...)
```

So how to link these records? We care about the date and the vin, right? For example, if a car was:

- Sold on 1 June
- Maintenance was performed on 12 May
- Maintenance was performed on 15 July

Then those `MaintenanceRecord`s link to two separate `OwnershipRecord`s. You can see how this would be an intensive task. There are a few different approaches to linking that I tried.

1. Offload each new maintenance record to Celery. Use query to find the right `OwnershipRecord` and create the ForeignKey relationship.

   ```
   match = OwnershipRecord.objects.filter(vin=mx_vin, saledate__lt=date_in_shop).order_by('-saledate').latest('saledate')
   ```
2. Perform a query on all records (or some batch subset) with new Django 1.11 tools `Subquery` and `OuterRef`. Offload to Celery.

   ```
   possible_matches = OwnershipRecord.objects.filter(vin=OuterRef('vin'), saledate__lt=OuterRef('date_in_shop'))

   MaintenanceRecord.objects.filter(<subset_criteria>).update(ownership_record = Subquery(possible_matches)[:1])
   ```
3. Do the operation in memory, in batches as small or as large as needed. Offload this to Celery.

   ```
   # this code performs the "batch chunking"
   id_extremes =     MaintenanceRecord.objects.filter(<subset_criteria>).aggregate(Min('id'),     Max('id')).values
   min_id = min(id_extremes)
   max_id = max(id_extremes)
   chunksize = 2000
   while True:
     # the .delay here is for Celery to pick up the job
     perform_linking_task.delay(min_id, min_id+chunksize)
     min_id += chunksize
     if min_id > max_id:
       break

   # this is how I linked
   def perform_linking_task(min_id, max_id):
     from collections import defaultdict  # These are great

     # I've ommitted the .values(...) bit of these queries for brevity
     mx_records = MaintenanceRecord.objects.filter(id__lte=min_id, id__gte=max_id)
     vin_list = [mrec.vin for mrec in maintenance_records]
     possible_matches = OwnershipRecord.objects.filter(vin__in=vin_list)
     orecs=defaultdict(list)

     # this is the magic - it makes a "hash table" of vins to records
     for possible in possible_matches:
       orec[possible['vin']].append(possible)

     for mrec in mx_records:
       current = None
       for orec in orecs:
         # Do matching logic here, put the best into current
       if current is not None:
         mrec.ownership_record = current['id']
         mrec.save(update_fields=['ownership_record'])
   ```

Comment: I don't think this is appropriate for StackOverflow as it does not configure a question, despite the title. This is more like a blog post.

Comment: There is literally an "answer your own question" option.

Comment: While you guys are downvoting, can someone help me fix the formatting?

Comment: This is possibly interesting content but ought to be posted on a blog - SO is for QAs, not for storytelling.

Comment: I have asked questions on SO about how to do this. This is the answer I wish someone had written!! Am I taking crazy pills? Who are you SO Gatekeepers?

Comment: Self-answered questions must still be presented as on-topic questions with actual answers. If you want to chronicle your breakthroughs, SO may not be the appropriate place for that. If you have further queries please take them to [meta].

Comment: @PANDAStack don't take this too personally, these downvotes do not mean people think what you posted is not useful or correct. It's just *not where it should be*. SO is a community-moderated question-and-answer board with rules about what goes where, and what is happening here is that people are 'moderating' through downvotes. If this is an answer to a question you posted previously, post it there as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score -1):

## Here are the results

1. Slowest. Measured in seconds per successful link.
2. Twice as fast as #1.
3. 100x as fast as #1.

Clearly, it's not ALWAYS best to do the heavy lifting in the database.